# Problem when equating date values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm running a bit of code that is in encased in a setInterval timer; among other things, before a certain time, it should display a "simulation starts at xxx time" message.

startdate is the time that the simulation begins, and I have defined the other variables as follows:

```
var d = new Date();
var da = d.getDate();
var h = d.getHours();
var mo = d.getMonth();


if ((mo != 3) || (mo == 3 && da === (startdate - 9)) 
  || (mo == 3 && da == (startdate - 8) && h < 21)) {
    document.getElementById("infoWindow").innerHTML = 
      "<p style=\"color:red;\">Placeholder text</p>";
}
```

So, if I set startdate to (say) 10 and the month is April, I should get a message on the 1st, and the 2nd, before 9pm. But when I run the code above it skips the section in curly brackets. I have set my computer clock to ensure that the code should work eg, setting it to April 1st, and April 2nd, any time from midday to 9pm, but I get nothing.

In firefox dubugger, when I put a break point in and look at the value of "da" in the "if..." statement, it says "false" and not a numerical value. Replacing the "===" with "==" makes no difference either as I thought it was getting confused with the returned date and a true/false return from the date commands. I cannot see what is wrong.

In other parts of the code, I have other checks to make sure that the code performs things on time, such as (da==startdate+5) and they run fine, it is just this one section that is causing problems

Comment: Off-topic protip: Single quotes for JS, double for HTML. Save yourself some backslashes. Also, you might abstract your conditions into a function to reduce that `if` statement to something more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, i tried `startdate = 34`, to make today check, then adjust my computer clock, still OK. Don't you forget any `<div id="infoWindow"></div>` in you html code?

```js
 var d = new Date();
 var da = d.getDate();
 var h = d.getHours();
 var mo = d.getMonth();
 
var startdate = 34;

if( (mo !=3) || ( mo==3 && da===(startdate-9)) || ( mo==3 && da==(startdate-8) && h<21) ) {
  document.getElementById("infoWindow").innerHTML = "<p style=\"color:red;\">Placeholder   text</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="infoWindow"></div>
```

Comment: No, I've put a <div> in, I just can't get the above code to work!